# PERCPU: allocation failed, size=256 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

> PERCPU: allocation failed, size=256 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk.

Is The amount of space for per CPU allocations limited?

How much percpu-space can I use in Linux kernel module programming?

---

Now I'm trying to create as many `workqueue_struct` as possible. My kernel is 3.10.

My result: I can create about 100000 `workqueue_struct`s, then I find error info (same as in the title) when I use the `dmesg` command.

My code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>//kthread_create is_err
#include <linux/slab.h>//kfree
#include <linux/sched.h>//schedule
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/workqueue.h>

u64 i = 0;
static LIST_HEAD(myworkqueuehead);
static struct task_struct *task;

struct MyworkqueueType {
    struct list_head entry;
    struct workqueue_struct *wq;
    u64 number;
};

void myfree(void)
{
    struct MyworkqueueType *tempwqtype,*n;
    list_for_each_entry_safe(tempwqtype, n, &myworkqueuehead, entry)
    {
        if(tempwqtype)
        {
            if(tempwqtype->wq){
                //printk("myfree():number=%lld\n",tempwqtype->number);
                //printk("list_del()\n");
                list_del(&(tempwqtype->entry));
                //printk("destroy_workqueue()\n");
                destroy_workqueue(tempwqtype->wq);
                //printk("free tempwqtypetype:kfree(tempwqtype)\n");
                kfree(tempwqtype);
                //printk("after free tempwqtypetype\n");
            }else{  
                printk("tempwqtype->wq is null\n");
            }
        }else{
            printk("tempwqtype is null\n");
        }
    }
    printk("has freed all the workqueue space...\n");
}


static int test(void *data)
{
    printk("kthread  create_wq start to run test()...\n");
    while(1)
    {
        struct MyworkqueueType *myworkqueue;
        if(kthread_should_stop())
        {
            printk("create_wq kthread begin to do myfree()...\n");
            myfree();
            printk("create_wq kthread stop...\n");
            return 0;
        }
        myworkqueue = kzalloc(sizeof(*myworkqueue), GFP_KERNEL);
        if(myworkqueue){
            struct workqueue_struct *wq = alloc_workqueue("myworkqueue",0,0);
            //struct workqueue_struct *wq = create_workqueue("myworkqueue");
            if(!wq)
            {
                struct MyworkqueueType *mytype;
                kfree(myworkqueue);
                printk("\ncreate workqueue fail...\n");
                mytype = list_entry(myworkqueuehead.prev, struct MyworkqueueType, entry);
                printk("current workqueue number=%lld.start to sleep...\n",mytype->number);
                msleep(5000);
                schedule();
                continue;
            }
            ++i;
            myworkqueue->number = i;
            myworkqueue->wq = wq;
            INIT_LIST_HEAD(&myworkqueue->entry);
            list_add_tail(&myworkqueue->entry,&myworkqueuehead);
            printk("%lld ",i);
        }
        else
        {
            printk("\nalloc struct MyworkqueueType fail...\n");
            printk("current workqueuenum = %lld",i);
            kfree(myworkqueue);
            msleep(5000);
            schedule();
            continue;
        }

    }
}

static int __init maxwqnum_init(void)
{
    printk("-----------maxwqnum-------------\n");
    task=kthread_create(test,NULL,"create_wq");
    if(IS_ERR(task))
    {
        printk("create task_struct create_wq fail...\n");
        kfree(task);
        return 0;
    }
    printk("create task_struct create_wq success...\n");
    wake_up_process(task);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit maxwqnum_cleanup(void)
{
    kthread_stop(task);
    printk("-----------leaving maxwqnum-------------\n");
}

module_init(maxwqnum_init);
module_exit(maxwqnum_cleanup);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("mjq");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("just a test!");
MODULE_SUPPORTED_DEVICE("WORKQUEUE");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest chunk available from a module from the per-cpu pool depends upon the current usage by other modules that are already loaded in the Linux kernel.

The size of the percpu pool depends upon whether the following configs are defined in the kernel config.

- **`CONFIG_HAVE_SETUP_PER_CPU_AREA`**
- **`CONFIG_SMP`**

A typical initial size of the per-cpu pool at boot-up is [**32KB per cpu**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/percpu.h#L12).

It can vary if the architecture specific `setup_per_cpu_area()` function is defined. The exact amount of memory reserved for the percpu pool is logged to the console during the Linux kernel boot. For example, *Linux kernel 3.2* on my *Intel Core 2 Duo P8700* machine, logs the following :

```
PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @f77d1000 s31616 r0 d21632 u53248
```

The percpu pool is 13 pages i.e. 52KB for each cpu, **104KB** total. The other numbers are `base address` of the pool, `static_size`, `reserved_size`, `dyn_size` and `unit_size` respectively.

---

**UPDATE** :

Compiling the Linux kernel-module(from the code in the above question) and `insmod`ing it, results in the following error :

```
[867955.300798] create workqueue fail...
[867955.300804] current workqueue number=198634.start to sleep...
[867960.315934] PERCPU: allocation failed, size=92 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk
[867960.315948] Pid: 26103, comm: create_wq Tainted: G           O 3.2.0-51-generic #77-Ubuntu
[867960.315955] Call Trace:
[867960.315973]  [<c1563ac4>] ? printk+0x2d/0x2f
[867960.315986]  [<c110335e>] pcpu_alloc+0x30e/0x340
[867960.315995]  [<c110339f>] __alloc_percpu+0xf/0x20
[867960.316032]  [<c10641b0>] __alloc_workqueue_key+0xd0/0x430
[867960.316047]  [<c1122f75>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x105/0x140
[867960.316065]  [<f93e50e6>] test+0x56/0x194 [kmod]
[867960.316078]  [<f93e5090>] ? myfree+0x90/0x90 [kmod]
[867960.316091]  [<c1069ddd>] kthread+0x6d/0x80
[867960.316104]  [<c1069d70>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0x80/0x80
[867960.316118]  [<c158033e>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10
```

Essentially, as additional per-cpu blocks are requested, the `dyn_size` can grow as required using [calls to **`pcpu_alloc_chunk()`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/percpu.c#L783). This internally uses standard `kmalloc()` calls to obtain additional memory as required. This will continue as long as a block of memory of required size and alignment continues to be available. Eventually this will fail depending upon the usage/fragmentation of the system memory, which is when you see the **[error](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/percpu.c#L785)**.

---

### How `pcpu_alloc()` works?

At initial boot-up, the per-cpu subsystem reserves a small pool of memory from the global memory available to the Linux kernel.

```
PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @f77d1000 s31616 r0 d21632 u53248
```

This is what the log describes.

> Static **31616** + Dynamic **21632** = Total **53248** i.e. 52KB(13pages of 4KB each).

As more and more per-cpu allocations occur using `pcpu_alloc()`, the dynamic pool keep growing in size. It can be non-contiguous and even sparse in memory. But as long as the alignment and size requirements requested are satisfied this continues successfully. This is because the allocation are made using `kmalloc()/vmalloc()`.

Eventually one of these calls fails as a memory hole satisfying the size/alignment requested is NOT available. That is pretty much it. Just as one cannot predict whether a [`memalign()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/posix_memalign.3.html) call will succeed or not, it is hard to accurately determine when `pcpu_alloc()` will fail. Especially since even other modules (and the Linux kernel itself) can be calling `pcpu_alloc()`.

For more details refer [**Linux-kernel/mm/percpu.c**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/percpu.c).

Comment: my computer: PERCPU: Embedded 14 pages/cpu @c2800000 s36352 r0 d20992 u524288. 14pages = 56kB. Is 56KB the largest mermory I can use for percpu variable?? Now i'm creating many workqueue_structS in kernel module programming---need to alloc percpu, and i can create about 100000 workqueue_struct in kernel 3.X.if 256Bytes ( PERCPU: allocation failed, size=256 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk ) for each workqueue_struct ,then 256KB * 100000 >>> 56KB??? i can't understand...

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that each workqueue struct is using 256bytes? More to the point what exactly are you trying? How can i reproduce it on my machine to understand the issue? Can you update the question with your code and describe the steps that led to the above error?...

Comment: e....Actually based error info using 'dmesg' command.error info: PERCPU: allocation failed, size=256 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk. Ok, I will update the question with my code...

Comment: Built and tested the kernel-module. Updated the answer with details of the results.

Comment: PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @f77d1000 s31616 r0 d21632 u53248.------
[867955.300804] current workqueue number=198634.start to sleep...------
[867960.315934] PERCPU: allocation failed, size=92 align=256, failed to allocate new chunk------then how to calculate ? d21632 means 21532 pages? how to verify that 198634 is the max number in your computer? By the way,are you an Indian?no offense...just curious...And I am truly grateful for your help.

Comment: Updated answer with a **How `pcpu_alloc()` works?** section. this should hopefully clear any doubts that remain. Yes, I am from Bangalore, India. Glad to have been of help. :-)